# Hello, I would like to link stations from a csv file on Neo4j?

Tags: csv, neo4j, load, relation

I loaded a station csv file on Neo4j:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://github.com/pauldechorgnat/cool-datasets/raw/master/ratp/stations.csv' AS row
CREATE (:Station {
   nom_clean:row.nom_gare,
   nom_gare: row.nom_gare,
   x: toFloat(row.x),
   y: toFloat(row.y),
   Trafic: toInteger(row.Trafic),
   Ville: row.Ville,
   ligne: row.ligne});
```

I would like to relate them by loading another csv file:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://github.com/pauldechorgnat/cool-datasets/raw/master/ratp/liaisons.csv' AS row
MATCH (s1:Station {nom_gare: row.start})
OPTIONAL MATCH (s2:Station {nom_gare: row.stop})
WHERE s2 IS NOT NULL
MERGE (s1)-[:LIAISON {ligne: row.ligne}]->(s2);
```

but I have the message (no changes, no records), I do not see the error in my order?

`Thanks for your help`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that the unique ID for your station is in `row.nom_clean` but you match on `row.nom_gare`

Here is a version that worked for me (but I do not know the data):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://github.com/pauldechorgnat/cool-datasets/raw/master/ratp/stations.csv' AS row
CREATE (:Station {
   nom_clean:row.nom_clean,
   nom_gare: row.nom_gare,
   location: point({y: toFloat(row.y), x: toFloat(row.x)}),
   Trafic: toInteger(row.Trafic),
   Ville: row.Ville,
   ligne: row.ligne});
```

And:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://github.com/pauldechorgnat/cool-datasets/raw/master/ratp/liaisons.csv' AS row
MATCH (s1:Station {nom_clean: row.start})
MATCH (s2:Station {nom_clean: row.stop})
MERGE (s1)-[:LIAISON {ligne: row.ligne}]->(s2);
```

I stored the x,y as a point data type. This would allow to perform range and distance queries.

This is a small dataset, for anything real you need an index (or better, unique constraint) on `Station:nom_clean`

For consistency, I would either use lower or upper case property names. Neo4j's recommendation is cammelCase.

Comment: ''I have another question, I want to create a 2-way relationship between each duplicate station:''
'''
MATCH (s1:Station)-[r:LIAISON]->(s2:Station)
WHERE s1.nom_clean = s2.nom_clean
CREATE (s1)-[:LIAISON_BIDIRECTIONNELLE {ligne: s1.ligne}]->(s2)
CREATE (s2)-[:LIAISON_BIDIRECTIONNELLE {ligne: s2.ligne}]->(s1);
'''
''but it doesn't work, do you know why? ''
THANKS

Comment: Looking at the data I imported via above cypher, I do see `:Station` with the same `nom_clean` properties, but they do not have any relationship between them

Comment: Yes, the stations that are duplicated correspond to 2 intersecting metro lines. I would like to create a relation between these 2 nodes which represents the correspondence on foot to go from line A to B in both directions. I hope I explained well.